# apache prevents php mail() from working (no SELinux)

Tags: php, apache, email, unix

**What's working and what's not:**

I have a custom sendmail wrapper script which only gets triggered by PHP-Cli but not when executing through Apache php_mod.

- When I run `$ php mail.php` everything just works fine, mail() returns true.
- When I run the same file through my Apache it does not work, mail() returns false.
- In both cases I get an entry in my `(php.ini) [mail function] mail.log = ...` file.

**The Question:**

So how would I fix this? 
I want it to work through both PHP-Cli and Apache php_mod.

**The Setup:**

- I set the `sendmail_path` variable in the php.ini file to my custom wrapper script.
- I do not run SELinux.
- I do not run AppArmor.
- PHP Version: 5.5.15
- Apache Version: 2.4.10
- System is: ArchLinux (Kernel: 3.15.5)

**The Config:**

[httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/knLQQZfS)

Edit:

As it stands the Apache has no access to the php.ini value of `sendmail_path`, how would I fix this?

The list of `disable_functions` in my php.ini is empty.

Output of `phpinfo()` on:

- [PHP-Cli](http://pastebin.com/gXXxVcmd)
- Apache at pastebin ID: rjjjtUXZ

Sorry but I'm currently not allowed to use more than 2 links in my question.

Comment: Check the user who executes php when invoked via apache. It's likely that apache user does not have sufficient privileges to execute or access the config of the sendmail_path stuff.

Comment: Ok you are right an ini_get('sendmail_path') revealed that it conatins the wrong value, how would I give it access?

Comment: check phpinfo() in both cases, check the location of the configfile, it likely differs, so make sure both places have the right configuration. 100% sure that the configfiles are not the same in the two cases

Comment: If the sendmail_path is not set up correctly, you can find out your sendmail path with 'which sendmail' and set that as the sendmail_path var

Comment: @AronNovak the `Loaded Configuration File` is the same. But the values  of `sendmail_path` differ.

Comment: @Oli please have a look at the Setup section of my initial question, there I mentionen that I have set a custom path (which works for php-cli)

Comment: Check your application if it calls an ini_set somewhere

Comment: I'm using a test script which only calls mail().

Comment: Also I just now tried to dirty hack the problem by copying my script to `/usr/bin/sendmail`, but to no avail.

Comment: Upload the full output of phpinfo() at a public place for both environments. I am out of ideas right now

Comment: what's the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/sendmail-replace-recipient` ?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1563 Aug  1 13:31 /usr/local/bin/sendmail-replace-recipient

Answer (score 0):

Is 'mail' in the list of disable_functions in php.ini?

Comment: No the list of disabled_functions is empty.
The PHP-Cli version would not work either if it were.

Comment: Not necessarily, CLI and Apache php.ini files will be different.

Comment: A clarification question about the question should be a comment, not an answer. Consider deleting.

Comment: Thats new to me... where would I find the say Apache php.ini?

Comment: Try an  'ls -al' of /etc/php5/ to see the different environment types (apache2, cli, etc). Inside each of these folders is a php.ini.

Comment: Sorry that sounds like Ubuntu. I'm running ArchLinux we only got one php.ini